# Non-serializable field in serializable class (transient keyword)

Tags: java, oop, serialization, transient

I have a serializable class that extends Servlet

```
public class FileDownload extends HttpServlet{
  @SuppressWarnings("compatibility:6754389671327954013")
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private ResultSet rset;
  ......
}
```

My Question is:

Is the `rset` object automatically converted as `transient` at compile- or run-time? or do I have to mark it explicitly as `transient`? (That is a warning brought up from my IDE JDeveloper).

Comment: OTOH, why would you store a ResultSet in a servlet?

Comment: educational kind o question :) it could be any other type of Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the field is not neglected by serialization - you'll get a `java.io.NotSerializableException` if you try to serialize an instance of `FileDownload`. Mark it `transient`. Btw, what is a `ResultSet` doing as a *field* in a `Servlet`? This is not thread-safe. `ResultSets` should be local variables only, in any context.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `transient` your own.But you cannot `serialize` an object unless it implements `Serializable` interface.ResultSet is such kind of object.

Comment: First sentence is meaningless. Second is incorrect: `ResultSet` isn't an object at all, it is an interface.